# Javascript does not show up on every page

Tags: javascript, prestashop

My site is http://littlehousearts.com.  I am using Prestashop and have added javascript to display a banner on every page load.  Currently I only have one banner image and it loads fine on the home page and category pages.  But it does not load always on the product pages.  I am able to view source and see the script tag appropriately in the source.  The tag I used is:

```
<script src="banner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The code in the javascript file is:

```
function random_imglink(){
  var myimages=new Array();
  index=0;

  //specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
  myimages[1]="<a href='http://littlehousearts.com/28_golden'><img src='/img/golden.png' width='943' alt='GOLDEN Acrylic Paints' /></a>";     

  index=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length);

  if (index == 0){
    index=1;
  }

  document.write(myimages[index]);
}
random_imglink();
```

The banner I currently have loading is under "earn credits" and displays Golden professional quality colors.

Any idea why this would not load on some pages? I tested it to load a non existent image and there should be a text in that position that reads `undefined` but that doesn't even show up on the pages where it is missing.

Comment: Can you give a link where the banner is not shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess it's that you have that problem because you use relative URLs.

Then, `banner.js` points to a file in the current directory. So, if you are in "http://littlehousearts.com", it points to "http://littlehousearts.com/banner.js", but if you are in "http://littlehousearts.com/a/", it points to "http://littlehousearts.com/a/banner.js".

Instead of this, you should use relative URLs to your site's root:

```
<script src="/banner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This way, it will always point to "http://littlehousearts.com/banner.js"

Answer (score 2):

No ad here

http://littlehousearts.com/drawing/84-stockmar-wax-crayons-8-colours-supplementary-assortment.html

It has;

```
<script src="banner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Which is not valid as its looking in the \drawing directory;

```
http://littlehousearts.com/drawing/banner.js 404 (Not Found)
```

So change the path for scripts in sub-directories or use the full url in src attribute.

Comment: Sweet! That worked like a charm thank you, I cannot believed I missed that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're assigning the first banner to `myimages[1]` since array indices are zero-based and JavaScript expands arrays dynamically, your array now has a length of 2. Therefore your random number generator creates indices 0 and 1. Your banner will only show up half the time. The other half of the time nothing will show up. You should change

```
myimages[1]="<a href='http://littlehousearts.com/28_golden'><img src='/img/golden.png' width='943' alt='GOLDEN Acrylic Paints' /></a>";
```

to

```
myimages[0]="<a href='http://littlehousearts.com/28_golden'><img src='/img/golden.png' width='943' alt='GOLDEN Acrylic Paints' /></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the js file in the js folder of your theme
2. For add a js file in your site, you have 2 solutions :

   - in the header.tpl file of your theme, add this code :
     `<script src="{$js_dir}myfile.js"></script>`
   - override FrontController.php (function setMedia)